# Germanic Philology: "translate" a word from indoeuropean language to the germanic language

Tags: phonology, historical-linguistics, ipa, proto-indo-european, germanic-languages

I'm having a philology test next week. One of the questions will be to "translate" an indoeuropean word into a germanic word, like: i.e. Agros -> germanic Akraz (i.e. "g" --> germ. "k" for Grimm's Law, excetera). I understood that there are some exceptions to this law, like the Verner's law. Are there other exceptions or can i say that every i.e. "p" turns ALWAYS into "f", or that every i.e. "b" turns ALWAYS into "p"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not affected by Grimm's Law?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/20201/not-affected-by-grimms-law)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Verner's Law is not an *exception*, since Germanic did not emerge in one sudden leap from PIE, it is a *complication*, i.e. there is another law that has to be factored in. Grimm's Law happened, and then Verner's Law also happened. You can't say "except for further developments under Verner's Law, *p t k* always become *f θ x*", because there are other complications. PIE **steigh* "climb" shows up in OE forms such as *gestīgan*, Icelandic *stíga* and do on – there is another complication (GL does not apply after a fricative). Sanskrit *téjate* "to be sharp" and OE *sticca* are related, which illustrates another kind of complication (not an exception) – this IE root illustrates the phenomenon of "variable *s*", that *s* just sort of shows up sometimes. You could say that the Germanic (Greek etc) form reflects the root *steig* and the Indo-Iranian forms reflect the root *teig*, i.e. the reconstructed root itself is not totally fixed.

The word "path" seems to correspond to Sanskrit *path-*, constituting what looks like a serious exception to the claim that PIE *p* turns into Gmc. *f*. It is, however, thought that this word was borrowed from some Iranian language into Germanic, thus escaping the effects of GL. The word *kitchen* likewise corresponds to PIE *pekʷ*, exemplifying an extreme "irregularity", except the Germanic word is borrowed from Latin, cf. *coquīna*. That is, sometimes words are borrowed. There are also "exceptions" (though I cannot remember a specific one) where a word is iconic / onomatopoeic, and the correspondences seem to be off (the expected sound change does not happen).

It has been a virtual axiom in historical linguistics that sound change is regular, but recognizing that regularity requires knowing all of the complicating factors.

Comment: re: the overused path example, something important to remember: “this explanation does however pose historical problems, given the limited distribution of the Germanic word” (OED).

Answer (score 4):

I would like to briefly add more info on how consonant clusters were affected by Grimm's law (based on a number of sources, e.g. Arsenieva et al. 2003; Ringe 2017, vol. 1 etc.). All the Proto-Germanic reconstructions are from Ringe. All of the exceptions below are well-known and usually studied in undergrad (at least, that was in my case).

- **s followed by an obstruent** (crucially, this is not only restricted to s-mobile):

Gothic stairno, OE steorra < PGmc *sternan- < PIE *h<sub>2</sub>stēr-s (cf. Latin stella)

Gothic fisks < PGmc *fiskaz < PIE *pisk- (cf. Latin piscis)

- **two obstruents:** only the first obstruent - if it's a stop - is affected:

Gothic ahtau, OE ahta, eahta < PGmc *ahtōu < PIE *h<sub>3</sub>(e)ḱtéh<sub>3</sub> (cf. Latin octo)

OE nift, Old High German nift < PGmc *niftī < PIE *h<sub>2</sub>nep-t-iH (cf. Latin neptis)

- **the coronal cluster *tst** becomes ss:

OE sess < PGmc *sessaz < PIE *sedstós

- **geminates** pp, tt, kk (often explained with [Kluge's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kluge%27s_law), if you accept it)
- **miscellanea:**

Gothic fidwor, OE fēower (PGmc *fedwōr) seems to defy Grimm's law, cf. PIE *kʷétuōr

Several proposals have been put forward, analogy (Ringe) or /kʷ/>/p/>/f/ (Krahe).

**word-initial PIE *gʷʰ > PGmc *b** (Ringe 2017: 127-128), Gothic banja, OE benn, cf. PIE *gʷʰen-;

PIE *gʷʰ followed by a nasal was not affected: Gothic siggwan, ON syngva, cf. PIE *sengʷʰ -
etc.